# Create a data frame from a complex nested dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a big nested, then nested then nested json file saved as .txt format. I need to access some specific key pairs and crate a data frame or another transformed json object for further use. Here is a small sample with 2 key pairs.

```
[
  {
"ko_id": [819752],
"concepts": [
  {
    "id": ["11A71731B880:http://ontology.intranet.com/Taxonomy/116@en"],
    "uri": ["http://ontology.intranet.com/Taxonomy/116"],
    "language": ["en"],
    "prefLabel": ["Client coverage & relationship management"]
  }
]
  },
  {
"ko_id": [819753],
"concepts": [
  {
    "id": ["11A71731B880:http://ontology.intranet.com/Taxonomy/116@en"],
    "uri": ["http://ontology.intranet.com/Taxonomy/116"],
    "language": ["en"],
    "prefLabel": ["Client coverage & relationship management"]
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

The following code load the data as list but I need to access to the data probably as a dictionary and I need the "ko_id", "uri" and "prefLabel" from each key pair and put it to a pandas data frame or a dictionary for further analysis.

```
with open('sample_data.txt') as data_file:    
   json_sample = js.load(data_file)
```

The following code gives me the exact value of the first element. But donot actually know how to put it together and build the ultimate algorithm to create the dataframe.

```
print(sample_dict["ko_id"][0])
print(sample_dict["concepts"][0]["prefLabel"][0])
print(sample_dict["concepts"][0]["uri"][0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for record in sample_dict:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record['concepts']) 
    df['ko_id'] = record['ko_id']
    final_df = final_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the data to [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) using a generator:

```
import pandas as pd
import json as js

with open('sample_data.txt') as data_file:    
   json_sample = js.load(data_file)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = ((key["ko_id"][0],
                           key["concepts"][0]["prefLabel"][0],
                           key["concepts"][0]["uri"][0]) for key in json_sample),  
                  columns = ("ko_id", "prefLabel", "uri"))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df

    ko_id                                  prefLabel                                        uri
0  819752  Client coverage & relationship management  http://ontology.intranet.com/Taxonomy/116   
1  819753  Client coverage & relationship management  http://ontology.intranet.com/Taxonomy/116
```

Comment: @FJ may be there is some problem in the "uri" wthen i run the following code it gives me error in the main data.
    `for key in data_dict:
        print(key["concepts"][0]["uri"][0])`

It shows list index out of range. I mean probably there is some missing/empty field in the main data.

Comment: @DataPsycho `data_dict` is the json (`json_sample` in my code)? What is the exception?

Comment: @FJ oh sorry data_dict is the full version of json_sample. So it has same structure but with the full data.

Comment: I lode the big file and then run your code it gives me following error.
`with open('output_json_20171031.json') as data_file:    
    data_dict = js.load(data_file)`

Comment: @DataPsycho contents or uri are empty in some fields, you can try list slicing: `df = pd.DataFrame(data = ((*key["ko_id"][0:1],
                           *key["concepts"][0]["prefLabel"][0:1],
                           *key["concepts"][0]["uri"][0:1]) for key in json_sample),  
                  columns = ("ko_id", "prefLabel", "uri"))` Would it be possible for you to share the entire file using Google Drive, DropBox, etc? It would be much easier to give you a possible solution.